# Java Performance Monitoring

Tags: java, performance, monitoring

I had number of queries executed by my java code. For each query, I need to monitor execution times. Moreover, I also need to monitor execution time of certain functions. So, is there any way doing this in an elegant way?

Comment: Asking for library suggestions is expressly off-topic, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open source project to do that. Here is an example code snippet from it.

```
  private final static int BASIC_STOPWATCH_ID = 
  Audits.mapAudit("example.basicStopwatch");

  public void tryOut(){
    final Stopwatch stopwatch = Audits.getBasicStopwatch(BASIC_STOPWATCH_ID);
    stopwatch.start();
    doSomeWork();
    stopwatch.stop();
  }
```

[Caudit](https://github.com/Cetsoft/caudit/) is on github.

Comment: With Jprofiler or other tools, you can just monitor an instant of time. With Caudit, you can monitor forever. just check it out.

Answer (score 2):

[Perf4J](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/) is the best solution for this.

Perf4J is an open source toolset for adding Java server-side code timing statements and for logging, analyzing and monitoring the results. For those developers who are familiar with logging frameworks such as log4j or java.util.logging, an analogy helps to describe Perf4J:

> Perf4J is to System.currentTimeMillis() as log4j is to
> System.out.println()

For further reference you can visit http://www.infoq.com/articles/perf4j

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure the execution time of a method, you could also use the `System.nanoTime()` method of Java. Which uses the highest resolution timer available on your platform. The time is a relative 'free running time' which can only be compared with other nanoTime values. (https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks)

It is however very important to keep in mind that Java needs a significant time to "warm up". Java runs its compiled bytecode in the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) and uses its JIT (Just In Time compiler) to optimize parts of the bytecode at runtime to increase performance.

If you want to have accurate measurements about execution speed, you should run your function several times, and do not use the measured times of the first runs. Take for instance the following code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import tools.Helpers;

public class DivideInlineShort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = args.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 10000; 
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            runTest(n, r.nextInt(8) + 1); // you need the random to prevent the JVM removing the loops
    }

    public static void runTest(int n, int ran) { 
        int counter = 0;
        long timeStart = System.nanoTime();

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            for (int i = ran; i < 100000 + ran; i++)
                counter += return1(i);

        long timeEnd = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(
            Helpers.roundedTimeInMillis(timeStart, timeEnd) + "\t\t" + counter);
    }

    public static int return1(int i) { 
        return i / i;
    }
}
```

The first 2 to 3 runs took my machine about 700ms, while the remaining 47 were around 370ms.
This could be explained because of the inlining optimization which kicks in after a method is called more then 10.000 times if I remember correctly.

So if you want an accurate measurement of the execution time of your code, you should run it multiple times on the same JVM instance and neglect the first few rounds.